# What happens to Cho Chang and Krum?

Tags: harry-potter

We see Cho Chang in *Goblet of Fire* and *Order of the Phoenix* and Viktor Krum in *Goblet of Fire*.

Do we ever hear what happens to either of them after that?

[image]

Comment: We see Krum in DH as well.

Answer (score 31):

### Cho Chang

According to a 2007 interview with [JKR](http://blog.nola.com/living/2007/10/new_orleans_students_give_rowl.html), after the Second Wizarding War Cho Chang married a muggle and seems to have lived happily ever after. It's not known whether she had children. We don't see her on platform 9¾,

> **Interviewer :** *Cho Chang?*
> **JKR :** **Cho married a Muggle.**

### Viktor Krum

According to the latest release on [Pottermore](http://insider.pottermore.com/2014/03/part-two-of-history-of-quidditch-world.html), Viktor Krum survived the Second Wizarding War and continues to play Quidditch. His fondest desire, having come out of retirement for the 2014 Quidditch World Cup is to win a final before he dies;

> *“Much interest has been generated by the return to the Bulgarian side of the previously retired Viktor Krum, who at 38 is old for a Seeker
> but whose stated aim is ‘to win the World Cup before I die.’ For this
> reason, Bulgaria is attracting support from those whose own countries
> have not qualified.”*

JKR also noted in a live webchat that Krum found love on returning to his homeland.

> **Q: Did krum ever find love?**
>
> **J.K. Rowling:** *Of course, though he had to go back to his native Bulgaria to do so.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Bloomsbury Webchat 2007](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2007/0730-bloomsbury-chat.html)</sup></sub>

Comment: As discussed [here](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/39082/in-harry-potter-and-the-deathly-hallows-why-is-cho-chang-still-at-hogwarts), Cho Chang appears again after those books too.

Comment: [*Did krum ever find love?* Of course, though he had to go back to his native Bulgaria to do so.](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2007/0730-bloomsbury-chat.html)

Comment: @Ibid - Good eyes. Added.

Comment: @Valorum - Once you're at updating, you may want to add some info about the outcome of the 2014 QWC.

Answer (score 24):

We definitely hear about both of them in the final Potter book, "The Deathly Hallows"

**Earlier about Victor Krum:**

> They were all laughing so much that none of them noticed the
>   latecomer, a dark- haired young man with a large, curved nose and
>   thick black eyebrows, until he held out his invitation to Ron and
>   said, with his eyes on Hermione, “You look vunderful.”
>
> **“Viktor!”** she
>   shrieked, and dropped her small beaded bag, which made a loud thump
>   quite disproportionate to its size. As she scrambled, blushing, to
>   pick it up, she said “I didn’t know you were – goodness – it’s lovely
>   to see – how are you?”
>
> Ron’s ears had turned bright red again. After
>   glancing at **Krum**’s invitation as if he did not believe a word of it,
>   he said, much too loudly, “how come you’re here?”
>
> “Fleur invited me,”
>   said **Krum**, eyebrows raised.
>
> <sub>*Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows*, ch. 8, The Wedding</sub>

**And later about Cho Chang near the end, prior to the Battle of Hogwarts:**

> Harry’s mouth fell open. Right behind Lee Jordan came Harry’s old
>   girlfriend, **Cho Chang**. She smiled at him.

...

> Before he could formulate a new question, however, **Cho** spoke again.
>   “If you’d like to see what the diadem’s supposed to look like, I could
>   take you up to our common room and show you, Harry. Ravenclaw’s
>   wearing it in her statue.”
>
> <sub>*Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows*, ch. 29, The Lost Diadem</sub>

Answer (score 5):

Cho Chang and Viktor Krum appear at least in one more book, the *Order of the Phoenix*, when Cho goes in a date with Harry (in fact, Cho appears a lot in the 5th book), and Krum seems to be pen pals with Hermione.