# What was Cho doing in Hogwarts in Deathly Hallows?

Tags: harry-potter

In the books, it's clearly written that Cho is one year ahead of Harry academically, but in Deathly Hallows we find Cho in the Room of Requirements with the other students. Given the fact that she should have graduated the previous year, what was she doing there?

More specifically, **how** did she manage to get into Hogwarts despite Snape being headmaster?

Comment: [Are you sure that Cho is a year ahead of Harry](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/199994/100430)?

Comment: @Alex the probability of that is nearly 0, in this way we can rule out a lot of information given by students

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the books, it is clear that Cho Chang arrived when the Dumbledore Army called everyone with the fake galleon.

> Harry’s mouth fell open. Right behind Lee Jordan came Harry’s old
> girlfriend, Cho Chang. She smiled at him. ‘I got the message,’ she
> said, holding up her own fake Galleon, and she walked over to sit
> beside Michael Corner.
>
> <sub>Rowling, J.K.. Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows (p. 474).
> Pottermore Publishing. Edición de Kindle.</sub>

For example, Fred and George were there too.